# Keyword: Selenium2Library.Wait Until Element Is Visible' expected 1 to 3 arguments, got 4

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to verify the name of the ticket with the RFW code below :

```
[Arguments]     ${Ticket_lié}   
Wait Until Element Is Visible      xpath=//div[contains(@data-id,"dy_ticketlieid.fieldControl-LookupResultsDropdown_dy_ticketlieid_selected_tag")]//div[@title="COL-209464 -  SI CREME  "]      ${TEMPS_MAX_ATTENTE_ELEMENT_VISIBLE}    la valeur du champ Ticket lié n'est pas bonne**
```

Can anyone help me check what I'm missing here please .

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem stems from having more than one consecutive space in the xpath. You should escape the extra spaces.

```
... xpath=//...//div[@title="COL-209464 - \ SI CREME \ "]
                                          ^          ^
```